# Comparison in python without functools.cmp_to_key(func)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I would like to sort a list after doing some complex comparison with the values in it. For instance,

```
sorted_result = sorted(unsorted_list, key=functools.cmp_to_key(complex_compare), reverse=True)
```

where **complex_compare** is the method that is currently doing said comparison.

However, I would like to do this *without* the use of **functools.cmp_to_key** because I was going through the python docs and I see that it says:

> This function is primarily used as a transition tool for programs
> being converted from Python 2 which supported the use of comparison
> functions.

I looked up and couldn't find a simple way of doing something similar and that is just *not transitional* (which I was a bit surprised by – not sure if I missed something). What is a good way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you provide details of the kinds of comparisons you need to make and why that logic can't easily be changed into a key based logic?

Comment: The Python documentation contains a paper thast explains how to use your own comparison function: [Sorting Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: @deceze this was inspired by one of the comparisons I saw and I was curious how it would work in general. For instance, if the key currently used is key=cmp_to_key(lambda s1, s2: int(s2 + s1) - int(s1 + s2)). Where I would need the "other" value to do something with it.

Comment: @spinyBabbler That can be done with a key without "other".

Comment: If you don't want to use that, then use a key function. What you missed is that *Python 3 supports key functions for sorting, not comparison functions*.

Comment: Primarily, but it's not deprecated, so I wouldn't hesitate to use it if it's really simpler to define a comparison function rather than an explicit key function.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a key function that will return some value for each element such that comparing those values will result in the proper order. Usually you can write a better one of those than Python can generate by converting a comparison function algorithmically.